# What is the best way to create Update Method using PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop

I have thinking of this from past an hour, but unable to understand the best way to add `update`, `Insert` feature using a class in PHP.

I have an `employee` table which has around 5 columns, so i have created different properties for it in my `Employees` Class.

Now i am unable to understand where to set these Values, in `__costructor()`, in `add_employees()` method or some other way..

If i set them in `__constructor()` then user must remember and follow the same pattern in writing arguments that i followed in writing the parameters.

I am unable to understand that is it a right way or should i use different approach to do this.

I have searched this on net, and found very complex examples, where people are taking argument in form of array, separating it, add loop in it and then put it into database.

```
Class Employees(){

    public $db;
    public $conn;
    public $emp_id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $gender;
    public $added_by;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db= new DatabaseConnection('localhost', 'root', '', 'employeesmanagement');
        $this->conn= $this->db->connectDb();            
    }

    public function get_employees(){

    }

    public function add_employees(){

    }
```

Comment: It depends entirely on the use case and as such this question cannot be answered. OOP isn't something just can just smack on your code.

Comment: you need to think of the single responsibility concept you should not add your insert or update into your constructor you should add another public or probably private or protected function to insert / update your employees.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but from where to set the Values of the fields. I was just checking an example where it was creating a class and getters/setters for fields. Is it a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a class before, that does only things related to database things. Here is the class

```
/**
 * CLASS: Database
 *
 * Description: This class deals with all database connection
 * across the website. If any class needs to use the database
 * it has to extends this one.
 *
 * @author: Andre Ferraz
 * @copyright: ^
 * @version: 2.0
 */
class Database
{
    /**
     * Holds Class Object instance
     *
     * @var Object
     * @access: Private
     * @static
     */
    private static $_instace;
    /**
     * Holds PDO Object
     *
     * @var PDO
     * @access: Private
     */
    private $_pdo;
    /**
     * Used to keep track of how many columns
     * has been found!
     *
     * @var int
     * @access: Private
     */
    private $_count;
    /**
     * Holds data from database
     *
     * @var array
     * @access: Private
     */
    private $_results = array();
    /**
     * Description: Instantiates PDO object
     *
     * @access: Protected
     */
    protected function __construct()
    {
        $host = Config::get("database:host");
        $user = Config::get("database:username");
        $pass = Config::get("database:password");
        $dbna = Config::get("database:dbname");
        try
        {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$dbna.";host=".$host.";", $user, $pass);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            Redirect::to(500);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Description: Gets data from the database
     *
     * @access: protected
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function get($table, $columns, $condition = null)
    {
        if($condition != null)
        {
            $query = $this->_pdo->prepare("SELECT $columns FROM $table WHERE $condition");
            if($query->execute())
            {
                $this->_count = $query->rowCount();
                if($this->_count > 0)
                {
                    $this->_results = $query->fetchAll();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
        //@todo condition == null
    }
    /**
     * Description: Very similar to get function, but
     * instead it just checks if data exists without storing
     * any data.
     *
     * @access: protected
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function query($table, $columns, $condition = null)
    {
        if($condition != null)
        {
            $query = $this->_pdo->prepare("SELECT $columns FROM $table WHERE $condition");
            if($query->execute())
            {
                $this->_count = $query->rowCount();
                return(($this->_count > 0)? true : false);
            }
        }
        return false;
        //@todo condition == null
    }
    /**
     * Description: Updates information on the database
     *
     * @access: protected
     */
    protected function update($table, $CV = array(), $condition)
    {
        if($CV !=null)
        {
            $columns = '';
            $x = 1;
            foreach($CV as $key => $value)
            {
                $columns .= "$key='$value'";
                if($x < count($CV))
                {
                    $columns .= ",";
                }
                $x++;
            }
            $query = $this->_pdo->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $columns WHERE $condition");
            if($query->execute())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Description: Inserts data into database
     *
     * @access: protected
     */
    protected function insert($table, $CV = array())
    {
        if($CV !=null)
        {
            // Join array elements with a string
            $columns = implode(", ", array_keys($CV));
            $values = '';
            $x = 1;
            // Put array key values into variables
            foreach($CV as $value)
            {
                $values .= "'".$value."'";
                if($x < count($CV))
                {
                    $values .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }
            $query = $this->_pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES({$values})");
            // Check execution is successful
            if($query->execute())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Description: Deletes data from the database
     *
     * @access: protected
     */
    protected function delete($table, $condition = null)
    {
        if($condition != null)
        {
            $query = $this->_pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $condition");
            if($query->execute())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $query = $this->_pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM $table");
            if($query->execute())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    protected function getResults()
    {
        return $this->_results;
    }
    /**
     * Description: Singleton pattern, prevents multiple
     * instantiations of the same class.
     *
     * NOTE: This is not needed. Only for "show of"
     *
     * @access: public
     * @static
     * @return Object
     */
    public static function instance()
    {
        if(isset(self::$_instace))
            return self::$_instace;
        else
            self::$_instace = new self;
    }
}
```

Which other classes like User class would extend and use all the necessary function from the database to get data related to the user. Have a look at the project. There are some bugs in a few classes (which I can't be bothered to fix at this point), but database class is working fine. I don't mind if you get reference from it.

Visit my github for the full project.
[Github](https://github.com/FerrazzzZ/mylib/blob/master/core/classes/Database.php)

Comment: Suggestion, why you do not put `if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME'))
    echo 'PDO driver unavailable <br />';` to ensure driver is installed.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ thanks

Comment: How does writing a (very much not OOP) wrapper for a db connection answer OPs question? @upvoters?

Comment: How does it not answer? How is it "very much not OOP"

Comment: You are globally importing "variables". You are introducing tight coupling which makes testing hard. `public static function instance()` basically creates a global. Which again also tends to be used to introduce tight coupling. Also without any explanation e.g. the `update` method will be vulnerable to sql injection. You are preparing queries without parameters and with some `$condition` parm which also probably also vulnerable to sqli. And finally OP asked how to set specific properties which is not even touched at all in your answer.

Comment: Note I don't want to pick on you nor your code, but when introducing vulnerable code to innocent readers I tend to point out flaws. A simple SQL injection vulnerability would be right here in your project https://github.com/FerrazzzZ/mylib/blob/master/core/classes/User.php#L54. An example of an XSS vulnerability would be here https://github.com/FerrazzzZ/mylib/blob/master/users.php#L34. And a simple example (although not dangerous, but annoying for the user) of a CSRF vulnerability would be here https://github.com/FerrazzzZ/mylib/blob/master/logout.php

Comment: Well yeah I agree with you about the last two vulnerabilities you mentioned. But saying its not OOP, I do not agree. How does the instance function create a global? Its only checking if the object is set to prevent it from being instantiated twice. How can you do a sql injection there? doesn't the PDO prepare function deal with that?

Comment: Care to hop into [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) for a second?

Comment: Yes please, would be great